# Try to load some text from another .php page without reloading the current page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

trying to follow this example here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

I have this code

```
function showVoteCount(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtVoteCount").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtVoteCount").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getVote.php?id="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

function showVoteUp(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtVoteMessage").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtVoteMessage").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","voteup.php?id="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

function showVoteDown(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtVoteMessage").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtVoteMessage").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","votedown.php?id="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

then i have a link with this code

```
echo '<a href="view_definition.php?id='. $row['id'] .'&voteup=1" onclick="showVoteUp('. $row['id'] .');showVoteCount(' . $row['id'] . '); return false;">Vote Up</a>';
```

What I am trying to do is

to get text returned from `getVote.php` to go inside `txtVoteCount`

and text returned from `voteup.php` to go inside `txtVoteMessage`

but what's happening is when `showVoteCount` is called from the link, text returned from `getVote.php` is overwriting both my `txtVoteCount` and `txtVoteMessage`.

So how do i make it work the way i want it to?

Comment: While it's great to learn the inner workings of ajax, you should let a developed 3rd party do the heavy lifting for you.  jQuery turned me on to javascript, and now I can't live without it, and even develop sites with node.js...it's asynchronous behavior was simple to grasp because of all the work I did with jQuery.  Also, jQuery makes the php easier as well.  json_encode is just about always the last line in all my php scripts now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if your xmlhttp variables are becoming global and stepping on each other? Try declaring your xmlhttp objects as "`var xmlhttp = new` etc...". Including "`var`" will change the scope of that variable so it is contained in your function.

How about this: change each of your functions to begin like this:

```
function showVoteUp (str)
{
 var xmlhttp; // add this line to all your functions to declare xmlhttp as a "scoped" var.
if (str == "") {
//... etc etc, the rest of your code...
```

Edit:
JavascriptIsSexy has a great article describing scope, and what you should be aware of when declaring variables:
http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-variable-scope-and-hoisting-explained/

Comment: Too bad I didn't have a chance to try this. I resolved it by using only 1 php file to return a JSON that returns 2 variables then parse the JSON and put it in the appropriate txtStrings.

Comment: I think the JSON method is the better option, but you might want to add that "var" in there regardless -- no point in polluting your global. Consolidating calls is almost always a good choice. Kudos for tackling pure JS Ajax instead of running to jQuery!

Comment: I got my JSON to work. But I am curious if your solution would solve my previous problem so I created some test pages to use the old method of hitting 2 php files and test.  Too bad the ftp to my site is down.  As soon as it's up I'll test it and if it works I'll accept your answer so others who might have the same problem can use this answer too :)

Comment: Groovy -- I hope it works! Do you do your development on the live site? I checked out "unurbandictionary", and noticed the sql at the bottom, so I figured you were doing some testing. Have you checked out XAMPP for developing locally? Very cool site, btw!

Comment: yeah i just develop and test right off the live site. I wasn't too keen on installing server on my laptop. The SQL at the bottom is just for fun to see :) as i have prevented SQL injections i am not too worried about people knowing my table structures. When i am working on a page i usually name it as someFileName2.php then when it's all good and perfect i rename it to someFileName.php haheh

Comment: That's exactly what it was. the "var" fixed the old problem.

Comment: not only that I discovered a bug in my JSON on my site where I click on multiple IPs, and each IP is supposed to go get location and show it, with out the "var" sometimes multiple IPs get the same location shown up, and it doesn't display all the ones i clicked on if i click on them fast before the response returns.  But with the "var" it fixed everything. Every location is slowly showing up afterwards as the response comes in and no IPs gets missed no matter how fast I click them. So this "var" is definitely needed. good find on your part.

Comment: I am surprised that w3school would post something that might cause a bug for in certain situations.

Comment: Well, the w3 example is totally valid, at least for their short example :-) When I learned about that `var` thing, I started *always* explicitly declaring variables with `var` (unless other behavior was desired) -- it can really bite ya if you're not careful. I added a link describing the variable scope to my answer for additional info. Also, I do recommend developing locally with xampp -- it's a great, easy, fast way to check stuff before putting it out there. Much faster than ftp-ing every change. Happy coding!